# CSS border used as lines, but needs to stop after reaches last child

Tags: html, css

What's happening is the lines from a child are being drawn all the way down the page, even when that child is the last. I've tried all sorts of code to make the lines end at the last child.

I know this is not a lot of detail. I think the code will speak for itself.

I'm using an `<ul><li><div></div></li></ul>` model. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.blackbox {
  width: 340px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #333A46;
}

body {
  color: #444;
  font-family: Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}


/* Framework start from here */

ul.tree,
ul.tree ul {
  margin: 5;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.tree ul {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1px;
  /* indentation */
}

ul.tree ul:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

ul.tree li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 12px;
  /* indentation + 2 */
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  /* default list item `line-height` */
}


/*left to right dash for line*/

ul.tree ul li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 13px;
  /* same with indentation */
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 31px;
  left: 0;
}

.list-box-solid {
  /*padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;*/
  background: white;
  width: 240px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.border-padding {
  margin-left: 1px;
  border-top: 5px #333A46 solid;
}

.list-box-dashed {
  border: 2px dashed white;
  color: white;
  width: 240px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.tree ul li:last-child:before {
  background: white;
  /* same with body background changed from auto to 1px*/
  top: 31px;
  /* line-height/2 */
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="blackbox">

  <ul class="tree">
    <li>
      <div class="list-box-solid border-padding"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">University of Somewhere</a></div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">Birds</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">Mammals</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">Elephant</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="border-padding">
                    <div class="list-box-dashed">+Create Group</div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">List item 2</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">List item 3</div>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">List item 3.1</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">List item 3.2</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">List item 3.3</div>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">List item 3.3.1</div>
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">List item 3.3.1.1</div>

                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">List item 3.4</div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul </div>
```

Comment: "css tree" gives me this on Google: http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-tree-menu-framework
Search for .tree li:before in the css...

Comment: Please provide your `html` and `css` code here. An external link may be used just as reference, but the code must be here. Also, in this case, an image showing what you expect to have yould be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bbarclay6/bd6grk18/2/).

Not sure what is different that caused it. I worked backwards from the original which didn't have the lines.

```css
body {
  font-family: Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Framework start from here */

ul.tree,
ul.tree ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.tree ul {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1px;
  /* indentation */
}
ul.tree ul:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  color: white;
}
ul.tree li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 12px;
  /* indentation + 2 */
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 50px;
  /* default list item `line-height` */
  color: black;
}
ul.tree ul li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 13px;
  /* same with indentation */
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 31px;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
}
ul.tree ul li:last-child:before {
  background: #333A46;
  /* same with body background */
  height: auto;
  top: 31px;
  /* line-height/2 */
  bottom: 0;
}
.blackbox {
  width: 340px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #333A46;
}
.list-box-solid {
  /*padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;*/
  background: white;
  width: 240px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.border-padding {
  margin-left: 1px;
  border-top: 5px #333A46 solid;
}
.list-box-dashed {
  border: 2px dashed white;
  color: white;
  width: 240px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="blackbox">
  <ul class="tree">
    <li>
      <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">Animals</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">Birds</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">Birds</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">Birds</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">Birds</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">Birds</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">Birds</div>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <div class="list-box-solid border-padding">Birds</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="border-padding">
                        <div class="list-box-dashed">+Create Group</div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use this:

```
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: did you try this? I don't think this will answer the question